# JSON Response is not getting in Android from google app engine servlet

Tags: android, json, google-app-engine, servlets

I am trying to implement http request response from android to GAE servlet. The request from from android is normal http post request. It working fine. The problem is i sending back to the android is json response. I created json objest using GSON (gson v2.2.2). When i tested in browser, it shows the gson format correctly.

The json fromat is,

```
{"data1":100,"data2":"hello","list":["String 1","String 2","String 3"]}
```

I tried to send this json by

```
/*json is my json format*/

response.getWritet().println(json);
```

and

```
system.out.println(json);
```

When i tried to read the json object in android, i am getting the exception,

```
Value <html><head> of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

Please suggest some other ways or help me to solve this, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your page is putting out HTML code (`<html><head>`) before it puts out the JSON. Either strip all HTML and then process the JSON (perhaps by putting the JSON in a special container so you can find it easier), or don't output any HTML and only output the JSON.

Comment: i didnt put any html in my json. Just look at my format. There is no html

Comment: It may be an error page then. When you do the exact same call in your browser, what do you see?

Comment: Are you certain your framework isn't inserting any HTML?  Use curl to manually test your API and verfiy that's what you're getting.  From the limited code you provide, it seems pretty clear that whatever you are giving the JSON parser contains HTML.

Comment: @TusharDhoot: i can log my json response when i tried in my browser like my json response i posted above.

Comment: @CoderDecoderEncoder right click the response page in browser and see whether it is plain text or does it contain html also. browsers don't show html tags. that may be the problem.

Comment: @CoderDecoderEncoder can you please share your webservice url and its parameters so that i can have a look